# Вопрос по работе браузеров и http

Tags: http, браузер

При переходе между страницами одного сайта клиент заново скачивает всефайлы по внешним ссылкам на странице - скрипты js, css, картинки и тд ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие файлы идут прямиком в **кэш** (промежуточный буфер с быстрым доступом, содержащий информацию, которая может быть запрошена с наибольшей вероятностью) и при необходимости подгружаются браузером.

То есть на ПК создаются временные файлы. Если на них поступает запрос от браузера, он уже **не скачивает** наново их из сети, а достает из своего временного хранилища.

Answer (score 1):

нет. подгружает закешированное. чтобы браузер загрузил новое содержимое (не из кеша), нужно нажать Ctrl + R, а если вы создатель сайта то при изменении CSS (чтобы посетителям подгрузился новый css) вы должны передать какой то гет параметр

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css?v=2" />